# is_dir failure?

Tags: php, filesystems

So, from a script running in `/home/a-spdb/www/sofa`:

- `is_dir("/home/a-spdb/www/sofa/uploads")` //returns true
- `is_dir("/home/a-spdb/www/sofa/uploads/talent")` //returns false

sshing into the server, the 'talent' folder clearly exists:

```
bash-3.00$ pwd
/home/a-spdb/www/sofa/uploads
bash-3.00$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwsr-x+  2 myusername  someusergroup      96 Nov 15 00:50 talent
```

I've tried deleting the talent folder and recreating it (just `mkdir talent`), but I still can't get is_dir to accept that it is a directory.  Any idea why?

Comment: What about changing folder's permission, try `chmod 777 talent`?

Comment: Tried that.  A- doesn't work, and B- there's no reason the talent folder needs to have execute permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, deleting the folder above the offending one (ie, deleting `/home/a-spdb/www/sofa/uploads`) and recreating it did the trick.  May have been an ACL issue or something.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running [clearstatcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)? As per [id_dir documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php), the result is cached:

> Note: The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a safe_mode restriction. Compare the UID of the script and the folder.

Comment: Calling phpinfo shows 4 safe_mode_* variables, all of which are 0 or null, implying that safe mode is off.  Further, both the script and the folder are owned by the same user- me.